# Jinja listing nested JSON using for

Tags: python, json, dictionary, flask, jinja2

I would like to list the contents of a nested JSON on my page. What changes to awesome.html need to be done to achieve this?

Is it not possible to list everything at once without specifying particular subcategories?

More specifically this part of code in awesome.html does not work:

```
    {% for each_category in content -%}
        {{ each_category }} {{ content[each_category].each_category.items() }}
    {% endfor %}
```

I tried using a second for inside a for loop, but did not work at all:

```
    {% for each_category in content -%}
        {{ each_category }}
        {% for each_subcategory in each_category -%}
            {{ each_subcategory }} {{ content[each_subcategory].port }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

This code works, but it lists only ports, while I want everything, not only ports:

```
    {% for each_category in content -%}
        {{ each_category }} {{ content[each_category].port }}
    {% endfor %}
```

---

## Extra info

## Sample contents of configs/env.json:

```
{
   "env" : {
      "db" : {
         "postgres_db_useradmin" : "devadmin",
         "postgres_db_useradmin_pw" : "sdfkjsnbdfjkgb",
         "port" : "2134",
         "app" : "sdfszdg"
      },
      "ssh" : {
         "ssh_user" : "ubuntu",
         "ssh_server" : "website.com",
         "port" : "22"
      },
      "app" : {
         "ht_protocol" : "http",
         "port" : "8080"
      }
   }
}
```

---

## Loading JSON in app.py, fragment

```
with open('configs/env.json', 'r') as json_file:
    env_dict = json.load(json_file)

content = env_dict['env']  # removing the top env category, because it is the only one
```

---

## Contents of awesome.html using jinja syntax that needs to be changed:

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Awesome page</h1>
     {% for each_category in content -%}
        {{ each_category }} {{ content[each_category].each_category.items() }}
     {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Similar question that I found, but could not adapt the solution to my case:

[Jinja parsing a nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59867396/jinja-parsing-a-nested-json)

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it!

The solution was to use a nested for loop and not use dot notation, but rather [ ] to refer to values.

Here I renamed `content` to `all_content`.

`each_category` is db, ssh, app, as keys of a dictionary.

`all_content[each_category]` refers to containers inside db, ssh, app, i.e. values of those keys.

`each_subcategory` stands for `postgres_db_useradmin`, `postgres_db_useradmin_pw`, etc.

`all_content[each_category][each_subcategory]` are values of keys `postgres_db_useradmin`, `postgres_db_useradmin_pw`, etc., which means `devadmin`, `sdfkjsnbdfjkgb`, and so forth.

```
    {% for each_category in all_content -%}
        {{ each_category }}
        {% for each_subcategory in all_content[each_category] %}
            {{ each_subcategory }} {{ all_content[each_category][each_subcategory] }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```